# How can I download the last supported/compatible version of an app by knowing the Android OS version?

Tags: google-play-store, downloading, android-versions, 2.1-eclair, compatibility

I have a very old samsung phone (Galaxy Ace) which runs Android Eclair. Surprisingly, Google Play and other apps still work and connect to the Internet, but there's a few problems. I had to hard reset it a few times, and all the apps I had were removed. Until last year or so, most of the apps were still compatible with my phone, but now they just can't be installed (they require a later version of Android I suppose, since it says "your device isn't compatible with this version").

So what I'm trying to do is to install every single app from an APK file, which I would download from the Internet. The thing is, I waste a lot of time looking for the **latest supported version**. This means I don't want an older version, I want the exact last version that was compatible. iOS has this feature, if you previously "purchased" an app you can actually download the last compatible version, but I don't know how to do this on Android.

Do I have to keep looking for the correct app version or can I get the last compatible version?

Comment: Android 2.x will be unable to use any Google related services after September 27th https://support.google.com/android/thread/118703101/sign-in-on-android-devices-running-android-2-3-7-or-lower-will-not-be-allowed-starting-september-27?hl=en Play Store never had the feature to download an app as APK. If you use Play Store you only see those apps and versions that are compatible with your device.

Comment: @Robert So do I have to manually check what was the last compatible version?

Comment: Your device does only support TLS 1.0 which is more and more discontinued by internet services. Therefore even if you find an old outdated app version the chance is high that it will not work as all online connections will fail.

Comment: No, your phone is simply no longer supported. Support for pre 2.2 devices in Android Market was dropped in 2017. Please erase your phone and then give it away for recycling.

Comment: @Robert I thought of searching for a specific APK file instead of using Google Play

Comment: apkpure or apkmirror usually have index for android version compatibility, but I doubt it goes so far back in time